# No handles with labels found to put in legend ERROR

Tags: python, anaconda3

I am trying to use pyplot and draw a cos function, but I don't know why "No handles with labels found to put in legend." message keep comes out.

### Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 6, 0.1)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

plt.plot(x, y1, label="sin")
plt.plot(x, y2, linestyle="--", label= "cos")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title('sin & cos')
plt.legend()

No handles with labels found to put in legend.
Out[18]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x24f86e49040>
```

Comment: I ran your code and the legend generated just fine for me.  As dumb as it sounds, did you kill and restart the kernel?  I know I've had some goofy matplotlib problems solved just by doing that before.

Comment: Would you please reformat the code in your question so it's more readable?

Comment: The code is working without error in pycharm IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In the legend section you should write something:

Look at this:

ax.legend(facecolor='yellow', fontsize=14)  -----> gives Error
ax.legend(**"this is a test"**,facecolor='yellow', fontsize=14)--->Error is gone

my mean is the bold section

Comment: That is not necessary, it works fine without any arguments in legend as well

Comment: yes, I know it's work s fine, but it gives a message which is: No handles with labels found to put in legend. I just explained what is the reason of such message and how he can handle it.